# Dividing 2 values in a column of dataframe based on common value in another column in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe, providing snippet of it:

```
Year       Result       Count
2000        lost          5
2000        won          16
2001        lost         12
2001        won          22
2002        lost         15
2002        won          15
2003        lost         12
2003        tied          1
2003        won          13
2004        lost          8
2004        won          20
```

I want to create a list of year wise win/loss ratio. I know how to to do it using dictionary and loop.
But what is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options:

*Option 1*: `pivot` + `division`, use `pivot` to create separate columns for `won`, `tie` and `lost` and then divide the `won` column by the `lost` column:

```
df.pivot("Year", "Result", "Count").pipe(lambda x: x.won/x.lost)

#Year
#2000    3.200000
#2001    1.833333
#2002    1.000000
#2003    1.083333
#2004    2.500000
#dtype: float64
```

*Option 2*: `groupby` + `agg`, group data frame by `Year`, and for each year `divide` the Count value of `won` by `lost`:

```
df.Count = df.Count.astype(float)
(df.set_index('Result').groupby('Year').Count
   .agg(lambda x: x.get('won', np.nan)/x.get('lost', np.nan)))

#Year
#2000    3.200000
#2001    1.833333
#2002    1.000000
#2003    1.083333
#2004    2.500000
#Name: Count, dtype: float64
```